# What does & do to dictionaries?

Tags: python

What behavior am I observing here?

As far as I know, `&` is the bitwise `AND` operator. Why does `a & b` result in a set?

```
>>> a = {1, 2, 3}
>>> b = {3, 2, 1}
>>> a & b
>>> set([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are `set`s, not `dict`

Comment: Your example wouldn't result in that output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not dictionaries, they are [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
>>> a = {1, 2, 3}
>>> b = {3, 2, 1}
>>> type(a)
<type 'set'>
```

The `&` operator when applied to sets means set [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection).

As for your example, the result would actually be `set([1, 2, 3])`. Set `a` and set `b` are actually identical because sets are unordered collections:

```
>>> a == b
True
>>> a & b
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

It gives the intersection of two sets.

In Python, below quick operands can be used for different set operations.

- | for union.
- & for intersection.
- – for difference
- ^ for symmetric difference

Here is the code:

```
# Program to perform different set operations
# as we do in  mathematics

# sets are define
A = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

# union
print("Union :", A | B)

# intersection
print("Intersection :", A & B)

# difference
print("Difference :", A - B)

# symmetric difference
print("Symmetric difference :", A ^ B)
```

Comment: sorry my mistake, edited it